# What is the best algo for matching synonyms?

Tags: java

I have tried Leveishtien distance algo. It does solve some of the problems but I want to know which algo can help me in matching the synonyms as well ?
Also, which is the best algo for forming the proper semantics of the string?

Comment: You must describe one algorithm in brief, you can also describe with example and data that you have.

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "synonym"? Surely not what one would mean in common language, right? Same goes for "semantics".

Answer (score 2):

There is no algorithm to find synonyms other than looking them up in a database (thesaurus).

Understanding the meaning of sentences in natural language or whole stories is still an unsolved problem in artificial intelligence.